# XPath for Google Sheets IMPORTXML - all text found between h1 and last p tag (including)

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I wish I had some progress to share, but nothing I tried seems to work :\

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IMPORTDATA("url")
```

and see if its possible for given url

backup formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("url"); 5000; 20)
```

Comment: This formula only works for csv / tsv formats, unless I am missing something.